# Looking for an intermediate to advanced Rails 3 book recommendation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm a seasoned Symfony 1.4 developer with a good handle on Symfony 2.0, so I'm a bit beyond the basics of frameworks.
I've recently built a solution with Rails 3 and would like to pick up a book to read up on how I could have done some things better.

I'm mostly using Rails as a database layer with very minimal in the ways of ERb.  Some topics I'd hope to see covered in advanced detail are:

- JSON
- Ideas and opinions on how to serve rich internet applications
- Good ActiveRecord usage and planning
- Writing models and keeping implementation out of controllers
- In general, conventions on controllers and actions

There are likely many subjects I'd like to hear about however I'm not interested in focusing too strongly on testing quite yet.

Comment: good blog post: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: This book has nothing to do with rails: its a Ruby book, but worth reading - "Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby" http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321721330

Comment: see: http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a bit of time with some of the books from the comments above, it looks like Rails Antipatterns is still quite worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't read this book, but it seems really good [Ruby Science](https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/13)